# Ruby on rails first project Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I installed Instant Rails on windows and tested using http://127.0.0.0:3000 on browser it showing WELCOME page.

Next : i started a sample application using commands

> rails hello
> ruby script/generate controller Hello index

with this it created a hello app

but i am when accessing http://127.0.0.0:3000/hello
it is giving me

**Routing Error**

**No route matches "/hello" with {:method=>:get}**

Comment: What does your `config/routes.rb` file look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a view called hello.html.erb in the views/Hello folder

Answer (score 0):

You have to set config/routes.rb up:

```
map.resources :hello
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html